# How to add capability in ChromeOptions for preference in the Chrome browser's Local State file?

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

This is what I have in my Local State file:

```
{
   ...
   "browser": {
      "enabled_labs_experiments": [ "force-compositing-mode-2@1" ],
      "hung_plugin_detect_freq": 2000,
      "last_redirect_origin": "",
      "plugin_message_response_timeout": 25000
   },
   ...
}
```

And I would like ChromeDriver to load my "enabled_labs_experiments" settings.
And this is what I tried to do in C#:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
options.AddArgument("--disable-logging");
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("enabled_labs_experiments", "[ force-compositing-mode-2@1 ]");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("localState", dict);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I don't think my code works as I browse chrome://flags with Chrome browser, that setting is still showing "Default" instead of "Enabled".

I also tried to change my code to:

```
dict.Add("enabled_labs_experiments", "force-compositing-mode-2@1");
```

...it doesn't work as well. Any idea what is wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 0):

I kown the way with java.Wish it can help you.And this answer can be found here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions.
Chrome extensions can be either packed or unpacked.  Packed extensions are a single file with a .crx extension.  Unpacked extensions are a directory containing the extension, including a manifest.json file.

To pack an unpacked extension, use the Pack button in chrome://extensions or use Chrome: "chrome.exe --pack-extension=C:\path\to\unpacked\extension --pack-extension-key=C:\myext.pem".  See the extensions docs for other ways to do this that are more automation friendly.  To unpack a packed extension, just unzip the file (you may need to rename the file from .crx to .zip for your zip utility to recognize it).
Installing extensions via ChromeDriver

Packed (.crx file)

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Unpacked (directory)

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("load-extension=/path/to/extension");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```